# Aligning matrices

Tags: horizontal-alignment, vertical-alignment, matrices

Sorry if this might be a very banal question. I am fairly new to LaTeX and I am having issues with matrices alignment. I am trying to achieve pretty much what is shown in this picture, I have tried with the `align` environment, but I found that it doesn't quite do what I'm after since I would like all columns of `Z`, `V` and `R` to be aligned, as well as all rows of `Z`, `Y` and `X`.

Is there a way to do it efficiently?

Of course, ideally the parenthesis around `Z`, `Y` and `X` would span all 5 lines as in regular matrix notation.

[image: I've done this with excel, but this is kind of what I'm aiming for]

Comment: If something needs to be aligned in TeX, nothing is a banal question.

Comment: Welcome! do you need the `A, B, C, D, E` in the output?

Comment: Thanks for al the replies, the letters are needed in the output, but I'm positive that now that I have an idea of how to do the alignment, I can put them there myself

Answer (score 6, accepted):

One way to achieve your layout objective is to use `pmatrix*` environments (in order to right-align all columns), `\hphantom` statements (to widen various columns as needed), and `\mkern` directives (to align the left-hand most columns of the `Z`, `V`, and `R` matrices/row vectors).

If you're not comfortable with `\hphantom` directives inside `pmatrix*` environments, you could load the `siunitx` package to define columns of integer values with widths corresponding to 2, 3, and 4 digits. In the example below, I suggest using `\mleft(` and `\mright)` instead of the usual `\left(` and `\right)` in order to avoid excessive spacing around the matrices. Note that the `\mkern7.5mu` directives continue to be employed.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools,siunitx,array,mleftright}
\newcolumntype{i}[1]{S[table-format=#1]} % columns of right-aligned integers
\begin{document}
First method:
\begin{align*}
Z &= \begin{pmatrix*}[r]
     \hphantom{000}0 & 70 & 0 & 30 & \hphantom{000}0 \\
     0 & 0 & 120 & 0 & 0 \\
     0 & 0 & 0 & 40 & 0  \\
     0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 70  \\
     0 & 50 & 0 & 0 & 0  
     \end{pmatrix*} \qquad
 Y = \begin{pmatrix*}[r] 0 \\ 0\\ 80 \\ 0 \\ 20 \end{pmatrix*} \\
V &= \mkern7.5mu \begin{pmatrix*}[r] 
     \hphantom{0}100 & \phantom{0}0 & \phantom{00}0 & \phantom{0}0 & \hphantom{000}0 
     \end{pmatrix*} \\
R &= \mkern7.5mu\begin{pmatrix*}[r]
     5000 & \hphantom{0}0 & \hphantom{00}0 & \hphantom{0}0 & 2000  
     \end{pmatrix*}
\end{align*}

\bigskip
Second method:
\begin{align*}
Z &= \mleft( \begin{array}{@{}i{4}i{2}i{3}i{2}i{4}@{}}
     0 & 70 & 0 & 30 & 0 \\
     0 & 0 & 120 & 0 & 0 \\
     0 & 0 & 0 & 40 & 0  \\
     0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 70  \\
     0 & 50 & 0 & 0 & 0
     \end{array} \mright) \qquad
 Y = \begin{pmatrix*}[r] 0 \\ 0\\ 80 \\ 0 \\ 20 \end{pmatrix*} \\
V &= \mkern7.5mu 
     \mleft( \begin{array}{@{}i{4}i{2}i{3}i{2}i{4}@{}}
     100 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0
     \end{array} \mright) \\
R &= \mkern7.5mu 
     \mleft( \begin{array}{@{}i{4}i{2}i{3}i{2}i{4}@{}}
     5000 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 2000
     \end{array} \mright)
\end{align*}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use the *matrix* library of *TikZ* together with the *positioning* library to achieve something like this:

### Code

```
\documentclass[tikz, border=2mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix, positioning}

\begin{document}

%\matrix (m) [matrix of math nodes,left delimiter=(,right delimiter=),
%  inner sep=2pt,outer sep=0pt]{
%  a & b & [1em] 0 \\
%  c & d & 1 \\ };

\begin{tikzpicture}
[   on grid,
    inner sep=2pt,
    outer sep=0pt,
    minimum width=9mm,
    every left delimiter/.style={xshift=3.5ex},
    every right delimiter/.style={xshift=-3.5ex}
]

\matrix (R) [matrix of math nodes]
{   A & B & C & D & E \\ };

\matrix (MZ) [matrix of math nodes, left delimiter=(, right delimiter=), below=1.5cm of R]
{ 400 & 0   & 0   & 0   & 0   \\
  0   & 0   & 0   & 0   & 700 \\
  0   & 0   & 200 & 0   & 0   \\
  0   & 300 & 0   & 0   & 0   \\
  0   & 0   & 0   & 500 & 0   \\
};

\node[left=2.8cm of MZ] (Z) {$Z=$};

\matrix (C) [matrix of math nodes, left=1.2cm of Z]
{   A \\ B \\ C \\ D \\ E \\ };

\node[right=3.3cm of MZ] (Y) {$Y=$};

\matrix (MY) [matrix of math nodes, left delimiter=(, right delimiter=), right=0.9cm of Y]
{   0 \\ 30 \\ 80 \\ 0 \\ 0 \\ };

\node[right=1.5cm of MY] (X) {$X=$};

\matrix (MX) [matrix of math nodes, left delimiter=(, right delimiter=), right=0.9cm of X]
{   70 \\ 0 \\ 10 \\ 90 \\ 0 \\ };

\matrix (MV) [matrix of math nodes, left delimiter=(, right delimiter=), below=2cm of MZ]
{   400 & 0 & 0 & 2000 & 0 \\ };

\node[left=2.8cm of MV] (V) {$V=$};

\matrix (MR) [matrix of math nodes, left delimiter=(, right delimiter=), below=1cm of MV]
{   4000 & 0 & 0 & 2000 & 7000 \\ };

\node[left=2.8cm of MR] (R) {$R=$};

\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

### Output

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Since the input in the OP's question has the appearance of a spreadsheet, it is possible that the OP would prefer a `tabular` solution, rather than one set in mathematical notation.  The only twist for adapting it was the introduction of `\mybig{rows}{glyph}` for making large parens.

Currently, column alignments are centered, but that is easily customized.  EDITED to incorporate `\arraystretch`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{scalerel}
\def\myvshft{\dimexpr+.5\ht\strutbox-.5\dp\strutbox}
\newcommand\mybig[2]{\smash{\raisebox{\myvshft}{\scaleto[2ex]{\raisebox{%
  -\myvshft}{#2}}{\arraystretch\dimexpr#1\normalbaselineskip}}}}
\begin{document}
\renewcommand\arraystretch{1.3}
\tabcolsep3pt
\begin{tabular}{cccccccccccccccccccc}
&&&&A&B&C&D&E\\
\\
A&&&&0&70&0&30&0&&&&&0&&&&&0\\
B&&&&0&0&120&0&0&&&&&0&&&&&0\\
C&&Z =&\mybig{5}{(}&0&0&0&40&0&\mybig{5}{)}&&
  Y =&\mybig{5}{(}&0&\mybig{5}{)}&&X =&\mybig{5}{(}&0&\mybig{5}{)}\\
D&&&&0&0&0&0&70&&&&&0&&&&&0\\
E&&&&0&50&0&0&0&&&&&20&&&&&20\\
\\
&&V =&(&100&0&0&0&0&)\\
\\
&&R =&(&5000&0&0&0&2000&)\\
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: @Mico Done, per your request.